# Is there a way to create a pandas dataframe column based on current sort position and another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple columns of data and I want to find where a value lies within its "class" as well as overall.

Here is some example data (let's assume the "class" we're measuring against is is eye_color and the metric is score):

```
raw_data = {'name': ['Alex', 'Alicia', 'Omar', 'Louise', 'Alice'],
    'age': [20, 19, 35, 24, 32],
    'eye_color': ['blue', 'blue', 'brown', "green", "brown"],
    'score': [88, 92, 95, 70, 96]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df = df.sort_values(['eye_color', 'score'], ascending=[True, False])
```

I want to create a column that would use the current sort order to give a value of "Brown1" for Alice, "Brown2" for Omar, "Green1" for Louise, etc.

I'm not sure how to approach and am fairly sure there's an easy way to do it before I overengineer a function that re-sorts based on each class and then recreates an index or something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby().cumcount()`:

```
df['new'] = df['eye_color'] + df.groupby('eye_color').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

Output:

```
     name  age eye_color  score     new
1  Alicia   19      blue     92   blue1
0    Alex   20      blue     88   blue2
4   Alice   32     brown     96  brown1
2    Omar   35     brown     95  brown2
3  Louise   24     green     70  green1
```